# How do you redirect pages from a subdirectory up one level to the root directory

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I have recently moved all the content on my website from being in the www.mysite.com/shop directory to being in the root directory.  This means that now I need to redirect any request to visit a page with the /shop directory back to the same page in the root directory eg.

```
www.mysite.com/shop/categories/washroom
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/categories/washroom
```

This needs to happen with all pages in my site that were previously using the /shop directory.

The closest thing to a solution that I have found so far is the following code

```
#RedirectMatch ^/shop/.* http://www.mysite.com/
```

however this redirects all pages back to the homepage instead of to the relevant matching page without the /shop.

Can someone please point me in the right direction, or if this has already been answered in here can you please post the link to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch (^/shop/)(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$2
```

Comment: Pleasure. Unfortuantely rewrite rules are about all I know how to do with regular expressions!